# .hatccess file to redirec to subfolder/subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am nto able to rewrite URL as I need.
I have the following document structure:

1) `root`  - root folder where .htaccess should be placed in

2) `root/folder1` - subfolder

3) `root/folder1/public` - this is folder where `index.php` is

Thus I need that `mydomain.com` would open `index.php` inside "public" folder. And all other requests would go via it.

I tried this, but it doesn't work (p.s. I am writing rewrite rules first time). I put it inside root folder.

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$1
  RewriteRule !^folder1/public /folder1/public%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Other than useless `RewriteCond` this rule is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar .htaccess like yours, so I edited a bit mine. Does this worked for you?

The condiftion for `.css|.js` is needed otherwise it will send as plain/text instead of normal `css/js`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js)$
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ root/folder1/public/index.php [NC,L,QSA]
```